# Google Cloudprint Printer offline while XMPP connection is open

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-print

I have a list of about 20 proxy printers. For two of the printers - they show as offline, even though the XMPP connection is active. I have verified that the connection still works.

I am receiving and successfully printing and marking print jobs as printed, yet two of the printers appear as "offline for more than a month".

In the past - this occurred when a printer didn't receive any print jobs after an extended period of time... but sending a new print job "woke" up the printer. This doesn't seem to work here.

Does anyone know what's going on? According to the GCP documentation, if the XMPP connection is open/alive - the printer will show as online. I have verified that is not the case.

Something curious is that the "last print job at" under google.com/cloudprint -> printer -> details is NOT updating. Despite the fact that these printers show multiple successfully Printed jobs. This field stopped updating on December 5th for all my printers.